# Mac OS and Visual Studio errors

Tags: c#, macos, terminal

This is the error I'm getting when I attempt to run this project. There is nothing more in this module than simple code enough to display "hello world" I am running the same exact version of visual studio on another macbook I have with the same exact settings and it works perfectly. Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.300/Current/Microsoft.Common.props(62,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/Users/indianacones88/Documents/C#:ASP.NET/myApp/obj/myApp.csproj.*.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [/Users/indianacones88/Documents/C#:ASP.NET/myApp/myApp.csproj]

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Update:

This is the code that is found inside in .csproj file

```
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design"            Version="2.2.0" PrivateAsse$
 </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Other info:

I used the terminal command dotnet new console -o "project name".
I have also had the same error when creating web app projects from the command line and directly creating a project inside visual studio.

No, my apologies I wasn't clear. I didn't copy the files I just have two MacBooks and wanted to set up a working C# environment on both. I downloaded visual studio on both. Attempted to create simple projects and one worked and the other did not. I have checked and the setting are the same. I'm not sure h

Comment: Looks like you are missing a `.props` file? Not sure how you got the code from the working machine to the non-working machine, but maybe you missed copying something?

Comment: Does your path have the `:` in it? It could cause issues if you do.

Comment: Show your .csproject file, and give a hints what kind of template did you use when you was creating project?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `:` from the folder name in the path, as this seems to confuse the Microsoft compiler, perhaps due to the meaning of colon on Microsoft operating system file systems.

Comment: Colons are also used as separators in the PATH environment variable in Bash.

Comment: The error message shows that in this case the user's folder structure includes a colon, which is the cause of this error.