# How to fix an imported project not found error in C#

Tags: c#, .net, unix, .net-core

Before I say anything, I am brand new to C# so if I am a little clueless please forgive me. I have trying to do a "dotnet run" on some simple code that I have. My computer is a mac so it is Unix-based. Here is the code that I am trying to run:

```
    class MyApp { static void Main() {
     System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, C#!"); } }
```

However, every time that I enter "dotnet run" in my terminal, here is the error that I keep getting:

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/Current/Microsoft.Common.props(62,3): 
>        error MSB4019: The imported project "/Users/steelwind/HardWay/c#:.NET/Chapter01/HelloCS/obj/HelloCS.csproj.*.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk [/Users/steelwind/HardWay/c#:.NET/Chapter01/HelloCS/HelloCS.csproj]
>        The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.

The file structure is:

```
  HelloCS
    -HelloCS.csproj
    -HelloCS.sln
    -MyApp.cs
    -obj
      -HelloCS.csproj.nuget.cache
      -HelloCS.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
      -HelloCS.csproj.nuget.g.props
      -HelloCS.cdproj.nuget.g.targets
      -project.assets.json
```

The expected output is for the console to output "Hello, C#!" into the terminal.

Comment: Based on the error message, It looks like you are working in a unix variant operating system. I would suggest that  it would be worth [edit]ing your question to add a tag relating to that. Also I'm guessing [tag:.net-core] would apply. Using the right tags helps the right people see your question.

Comment: just updated the tags and some text. thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57742676/visual-studio-2019-for-mac-can-not-build-xamarin-forms-project

Comment: Another similar one but with nothing too useful (I'm just linking the questions together since they seem related... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56759959/mac-os-and-visual-studio-errors so you are clearly not alone.

Comment: I solved the problem. I just had to get rid of the : in my path and it is working fine now. Thank you for all of ur help!

Answer (score 2):

Removing the colon (:) from your directory path should fix the issue, I'm not certain why it breaks it but it probably has something to do with how in Windows you cannot have a colon in a folder or filename.

Answering for visibility for future visitors.

Comment: This worked for me thousandths of thank yous! For me the colon was in the windows disk name mounted on a Linux box.